# Can a wifi adapter drastically change my internet speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I'm kinda confused with how wifi adapters like netgear work when it comes to internet speed. From what I can tell it's used for faraway workstations or any devices which are far away from the router space, i understand that it can bring up the speed to the amount which you are supposed to get but, when looking on the descriptions of wifi adapter it can sometimes say up to 300 mbps or more etc. So if i were to buy one of those and have an broadband speed of up to 50mbps will that 50mbps rise up to 300 mbps as long as you are within the wifi adapter range?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> "[broadband speed of] 50mbps rise up to 300 mbps"

NO.

The speed is determined by the slowest component in the chain.

You will potentially have 300Mbps *on your LAN* (again, dependent on the slowest component in the connected chain, including switches etc.), but anything that comes or goes through the broadband connection is limited or choked by that broadband connection's capabilities.

You can think of it like a relay race with two Olympic champions and one 3 year old child. Adding another Olympian will not speed up the 3yo.

Comment: Its worth adding that 300mbit on wifi is a theoretical limit and outside a lab you will never get throughput close to that.